# CSS Transition for Website Issue

Tags: css

```css
.learn-more {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-transform: none;
        max-width: 155px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #363636;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .learn-more:hover {
        color: #21C8FF;
        transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<a class="learn-more" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
```

So I was working on my Website and I added a CSS transition so when you hover over something it fades into a color red. Very simple. I was just using...

transition: .3s ease-in-out;

-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;

But when I unhover it just cuts out. I want to add a transition so it fades back to its original color. Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

TrifleTower

Comment: It'd help if you could create a fiddle to demonstrate what happens

Comment: Sure give me 2 minutes.

Comment: Added into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the transition only for the hover state. if you want the transition to persist to multiple states just add it to the `.learn-more` class. Like this:

```css
.learn-more {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-transform: none;
        max-width: 155px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #363636;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        /* Moved */
        transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .learn-more:hover {
        color: #21C8FF;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<a class="learn-more" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the transition codes in the `:hover` state. Use it in the original class instead.

```css
.learn-more {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: none;
  max-width: 155px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #363636;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;  // here
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;  // here
}

.learn-more:hover {
  color: #21C8FF;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="learn-more" href="about.html">Learn More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the transition properties directly under `.learn-more` and away from the `:hover` state.

See a sample here:

```css
.the-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: limegreen;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.the-div:hover {
  background: #f50;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-div"></div>
```